# $HTTP_POST_FILES isn't working

Tags: php, upload

It's not showing the details of the files so I'm not sure if they are even uploading or not. Here is the start index.php file with the form:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Multiple File Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="multiple_upload_ac.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
  Select file
  <input name="ufile[]" type="file" id="ufile[]" size="50" />
  <br>
  Select file
  <input name="ufile[]" type="file" id="ufile[]" size="50" />
  <br>
  Select file
  <input name="ufile[]" type="file" id="ufile[]" size="50" />
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the page it posts to (multiple_upload_ac.php):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Upload Details</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php       
  echo "File Name :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name'][0]."<BR/>"; 
  echo "File Size :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['size'][0]."<BR/>"; 
  echo "File Type :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['type'][0]."<BR/>"; 

  echo "File Name :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name'][1]."<BR/>"; 
  echo "File Size :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['size'][1]."<BR/>"; 
  echo "File Type :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['type'][1]."<BR/>"; 

  echo "File Name :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name'][2]."<BR/>"; 
  echo "File Size :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['size'][2]."<BR/>"; 
  echo "File Type :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['type'][2]."<BR/>"; 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

But something is wrong because i'm getting empty output:

File Name :
File Size :
File Type :
File Name :
File Size :
File Type :
File Name :
File Size :
File Type :

I've tried to keep the code to a minimum while replicating the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: what ever reference said use `$HTTP_POST_FILES` is very dated, stop using it. you should be using `$_FILES`

Comment: How do i get the name of the file, for example, from $_FILES? $_FILES[0]['name']; something like that?

Comment: `print_r($_FILES);` will show you what you have to work with

Comment: Thanks heaps mate got it working, you're a champ!